# how to select the current selected dropdown option in a table td element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

//on selecting the current td element in each dropdown down in a row i want to disable the corresponding input td element 
        but this code is working only for the first dropdown

```
     <html>
        <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#d1").bind('change',function(){

        if($(this).closest('tr').find('#d1').val() == 'saab'){

        $("#d2").attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
            } 
        else{
        $("#d2").removeAttr('disabled');
        }  
        });
        });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>Cab</h1>
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td class="select">Online Password (Repeated)&nbsp; </td>
                <td><select name="D1" id="d1">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                </select></td>
              <td >
            <input type="text" value="" id="d2">
<!-- above is the input textbox i want to disable-->
          </td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td class="select">Online Password (Repeated)&nbsp; </td>
                <td><select name="D1" id="d1">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                </select></td>
              <td >
            <input type="text" value="" id="d2">
          </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="select">Online Password (Repeated)&nbsp; </td>
                <td><select name="D1" id="d1">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                </select></td>
              <td>
            <input type="text" value="" id="d2">
          </td>
            </tr>
           <tr>

          </tr>
        </table>


        </body>
        </html>
```

// the function which i wrote is working only for the first td element , on selecting the second dropdown td the function call itself is not happening.

Comment: `ID`'s should be unique, maybe a using a class for this would be better?

Comment: On selection of the corresponding tr td dropdown , i want to disable the same tr td input element but this code is working only for the first tr td select dropdown i.e  the function call is happening only once for the first

Comment: i want with same id as these dropdowns are coming as a string with hardcoded id which is same for all the dropdowns.

Comment: @vijayram you should not have multiple same id elements this is against the HTML specifications

Comment: Then don't use the `ID`'s as a selector, use a `class` just like I have in my answer below but I would recommend you find a way to replace those `ID`'s to make them unique. If you plan to target them for submitting then you might find further problems if you don't use a `class` to compensate for those `ID`'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues in you code.

1: HTML has duplicated id element which make html invalid.

2: You are attaching event with id selector which should be done if you want to bind an event with single element.

3: The selector used for find the input in same row are wrong again.

Try the below code.

I have changed the id attribute in your html to class and changed the logic to find the input element next to the select.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".d1").on('change', function() {
      var context = ($(this).parents("tr"));
      if ($(this).val() == 'saab') {
        $(".d2",context).attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
      } else {
         $(".d2",context).removeAttr('disabled');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Cab</h1>
  <table border="0">
    <tr>
      <td class="select">Online Password (Repeated)&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <select name="D1" class="d1">
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="" class="d2">
        <!-- above is the input textbox i want to disable-->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="select">Online Password (Repeated)&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <select name="D1" class="d1">
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="" class="d2">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="select">Online Password (Repeated)&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <select name="D1" class="d1">
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="" class="d2">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>
  </table>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but thanks a lot for correcting me

Comment: @vijayram NP Glad to help :)

Comment: @Deep beat me by seconds :p

Comment: @NewToJS yeah mine was perhaps 50 second earlier :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `class` for something like this.

I have removed the duplicate `ID`'s and added a `class` name of **options**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".options").bind('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'saab') {
      $(this).closest('tr').find('input').attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
    } else {
      $(this).closest('tr').find('input').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="select">Online Password (Repeated)&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <select name="D1" class="options">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="">
      <!-- above is the input textbox i want to disable-->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="select">Online Password (Repeated)&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <select name="D1" class="options">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="select">Online Password (Repeated)&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <select name="D1" class="options">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> **UPDATE:** *"i want with same id as these dropdowns are coming as a string with hardcoded id which is same for all the dropdowns"*

If you cannot add a `class` to those elements or edit the `ID`'s then this will work but I really do recommend you find a way to edit those `ID`'s and use a `class` name. This method will function just fine with no editing required to the HTML elements.

I have changed the selector to `"select[id=d1]"`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select[id=d1]").bind('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'saab') {
      $(this).closest('tr').find('input').attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
    } else {
      $(this).closest('tr').find('input').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="select">Online Password (Repeated)&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <select name="D1" id="d1">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="" id="d2">
      <!-- above is the input textbox i want to disable-->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="select">Online Password (Repeated)&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <select name="D1" id="d1">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="" id="d2">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="select">Online Password (Repeated)&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <select name="D1" id="d1">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="" id="d2">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you have any questions about the source code above please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: thanks a ton , this is what happens  overlooking the basics

Comment: @vijayram No problem. If you have any questions feel free to ask and I will be happy to help in any way I can.

Comment: @vijayram I have added a second method due to your comment *"dropdowns are coming as a string with hardcoded"*.